# Syntax Error when Importing Data into SQL Server with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, pyodbc

Syntax Error PYODBC

Hi All,

I've been looking at this code for far too long now and can't spot the error. I'm trying to import data that I've pulled out of xml files into a database. When I run the program though I get a syntax error, and the try: gets highlighted. I can't find the error. Thanks everyone.

```
for x in range(len(sentences)):
    slice2 = sentences[max(0,x-1):min(len(sentences),x+2)]
    sentencelist.append([dewiki.from_string(s) for s in slice2])
    if "theory" in sentences[x].lower():
        slice1 = sentences[max(0,x-1):min(len(sentences),x+2)]
        surroundingsentences.append(['[[[&t]]]' + dewiki.from_string(s) for s in slice1])
        slicelinks.append([(links.findall(s)) for s in slice1])
    query1 = unicode("""INSERT INTO SENTENCE (TheoryDocID, SliceWithMarkUp, SliceText) VALUES ({},'{}','{}')""".format(id, slice2.replace("'","''"), slice1.replace("'","''")
    try:                                                                                                                   
        cur.execute(query1)
        cur.commit()
    except:
        print query1
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing two closing brackets for the line

```
query1 = unicode("""INSERT INTO SENTENCE (TheoryDocID, SliceWithMarkUp, SliceText) VALUES ({},'{}','{}')""".format(id, slice2.replace("'","''"), slice1.replace("'","''")
```

Which should be:

```
unicode("""INSERT INTO SENTENCE (TheoryDocID, SliceWithMarkUp, SliceText) VALUES ({},'{}','{}')""".format(id, slice2.replace("'","''"), slice1.replace("'","''")))
```

Comment: That was a Nice Catch!